# How to fetch wordpress post author details with react js?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, wordpress

When I try to fetch my wordpress site users like this :

```
https://sitename/wp-json/wp/v2/users
```

But it throws an error which is :

```
<title> 403 Forbidden
    </title>
```

How can I fetch my wordpress site users details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a `_embedd` query to the url

Answer (score 0):

Error might be coming due to the access permission which you are not having or maybe you are trying to open in your web browser that you’re not allowed to access. So you can try to check how you can get the access for particular site.